# ggraph maintain layout after edge removal

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph

I would like to maintain graph layout (vertex position) after removing edges. An example:

```
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

# create sample graph
g <- structure(list(from = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
               to = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(g)

# plot with all edges 
ggraph(g, layout = 'tree') + 
  geom_edge_diagonal() +
  geom_node_point(size = 10) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Now remove a couple edges and replot

```
g2 <- delete.edges(g, c(3,5))

ggraph(g2, layout = 'tree') + 
  geom_edge_diagonal() +
  geom_node_point(size = 10) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Whereas this is the desired output:

[image]

Is there a simple way to maintain vertex positions after edge removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing out the question I figured it out, you just need to save the layout from the first graph using `igraph::layout_as_tree` (or any other layout), which can be used for the second plot:

```
l <- igraph::layout_as_tree(g)

ggraph(g2, layout = l) + 
  geom_edge_diagonal() +
  geom_node_point(size = 10) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Hopefully this saves someone else a bit of time.